Problem with bone rotation
i have little experience in blender.
When the root bone (bone.root) is rotated, the following happens:

I can't figure out why bone.007 is turning and how to fix it?


Hello and welcome. Please verbally describe what your issue is, be specific and and use relevant keywords. Avoid referencing images or links as alternative to words, try to stay away from vague references like "this happens", "issue with", "like so", which make the post impossible to find for someone using search. Instead describe what "it" is, be descriptive, succinct and detailed. It may not be immediately obvious to users trying to help what you mean. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

It seems to be coming from your Limit Rotation constraint. Because the Y axis is along the bone, and it effectively rotates in worldspace when the whole rig rotates, it makes the constraint reach one extreme of the limit, and it then snaps to the other limit.

You seem to want that bone to remain vertical, I wouldn't use such constraint for that.
A simpler way would be do disable Inherit Rotation from the bone parent relationship:

This way no matter what happens from the parent, the bone will remain vertical  and you can still manually rotate it if needed:

